# Japanese term for when the Sushi chef prepares meal for you

Tags: sushi, asian-cuisine, language

What is the Japanese term for when the sushi chef prepares a sushi meal for you based on what the sushi chef deems to be fresh and good, as well as what you would be interested in eating?

I believe this is a term or style.  There's generally no ordering off a set menu.

Comment: I've eaten a lot of sushi in my life but have never been brave enough to try this. I think I should. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Dinah, do. But only do it with a really good and creative sushi chef. They will give your tastebuds orgasms.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Omakase.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omakase

Comment: The very model of an answerable question.

Comment: @Michael: but not of a modern major general

Comment: Haha, I love the Gilbert and Sullivan reference....

Comment: He's got information animal, vegetable and mineral.